# What is the proper way to sort by time?

Tags: php, datetime, date

When each item is entered into the db i use the following method to insert date:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
 ob_start();
 $createdon = date('l, F j, Y, h:i A');
 ob_get_clean();
```

This outputs something like:

```
  Tuesday, May 3, 2011, 04:50 PM
```

This is the query:

```
  select test_id, why_test, date_time
  from the_test
  where p_id = '$id'
  UNION
  select pencil_id, pencil_name, date_time
  from pencils
  where p_id = '$id'
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Now when i user the order by function it doesn't do it properly.  The dates are still being mixed up.  I used order by date_time DESC.

I am using php/phpmyadmin.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats your table structure like? `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` and make sure you're storing your dates as either TIMESTAMP or DATETIME fields

Comment: converting that just make me lose all the dates.

Comment: That's becdause you've stored your dates as strings in a format that PHP doesn't understand. PHP's standard date/time string format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Since your `date_time` field is a string, PHP's sorting its contents as a string, which means December comes before February

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing a date as a string is wrong. You should store a date as a date.

MySQL has a selection of appropriate types relating to dates and times; I'd recommend either `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` (probably the latter; look it up in the manual to see what's best for you).

To avoid losing your existing data when you fix your table structure:

- Add a field with the right type;
- Update each row in your table to copy the data to the new field, possibly with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function — this is a one-time copy, which might take some time;
- Delete the old field and starting using the new one instead.

`ORDER BY` will work naturally on this field, as you will now be using MySQL as it is designed to be used.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` takes into account the current timezone and can automatically convert to the server timezone if the connection timezone is different. `DATETIME` doesnt keep a relationship to the timezone.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT .... ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_time`) DESC
```

The idea here, is to turn a string into a number that can be sorted. A unix timestamp, if you are not familiar with it, is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, so if you can convert the time into that, you get a linear, easy way to compare time.

but I believe MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` requires a string in the format: `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

But the concept remains, into turning the date (or even storing it) as a unix timestamp or MySQL's native date types like `datetime` or `timestamp`

Comment: @hexa hey thanks! that worked but it by default only does ASC when i try DESC it doesn't do it.

Comment: using the `date` instead of 'date' returned to the old problem.

Comment: @hexa: What a horrendously inefficient thing to do.

Comment: @Tomalak indeed. But i'm guessing he stored the date in a string formated like that. How would you do it, if the date was stored in a string like that? Do tell.

Comment: @hexa: The recommendation would be to fix the database structure.

Comment: @AAA: By storing your data in a field with the proper Date-Time type in the first place. MySQL has a selection of appropriate types.